# How to remove a row from HTML table in XSLT template

Tags: html, xml, xslt, html-table

I'm a new StackOverflow member. I have a question regarding the XSLT template which transform my XML to HTML.

Here is the rough XML

```
<TopTerm ID="1" Entity="Term" Name="ENVIRONMENTAL MANAGEMENT">
    <ChildTerm ID="8" Entity="Term" Name="Auditing">
        <ChildTerm ID="36" Entity="Term" Name="Environmental audit" />
        <ChildTerm ID="46" Entity="Term" Name="Type of audit []" />
    </ChildTerm>
    <ChildTerm ID="11" Entity="Term" Name="Incidents">
        <ChildTerm ID="71" Entity="Term" Name="Bruce Beresford" />
        <ChildTerm ID="35" Entity="Term" Name="Case name" />
        <ChildTerm ID="83" Entity="Term" Name="Jack Lemmon" />
        <ChildTerm ID="87" Entity="Term" Name="Mary  Pcikford" />
    </ChildTerm>
    <ChildTerm ID="16" Entity="Term" Name="Monitoring" />
    <ChildTerm ID="18" Entity="Term" Name="Policies and procedures" />
</TopTerm>
<TopTerm ID="4" Entity="Term" Name="HUMAN RESOURCE MANAGEMENT">
    <ChildTerm ID="7" Entity="Term" Name="Agreements" />
    <ChildTerm ID="14" Entity="Term" Name="Leave">
        <ChildTerm ID="32" Entity="Term" Name="Annual leave">
            <ChildTerm ID="42" Entity="Term" Name="Name of position" />
            <ChildTerm ID="46" Entity="Term" Name="Type of audit []" />
            <ChildTerm ID="48" Entity="Term" Name="Type of product" />
        </ChildTerm>
        <ChildTerm ID="38" Entity="Term" Name="Maternity leave" />
    </ChildTerm>
    <ChildTerm ID="17" Entity="Term" Name="Performance management" />
    <ChildTerm ID="20" Entity="Term" Name="Recruiting">
        <ChildTerm ID="42" Entity="Term" Name="Name of position" />
    </ChildTerm>
    <ChildTerm ID="21" Entity="Term" Name="Remuneration" />
    <ChildTerm ID="12" Entity="Term" Name="Insurance" />
</TopTerm>
```

Here is my XSLT

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>                  
                <title>Classification plan and Thesaurus</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="wrapper">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Process</td>
                            <td>Function</td>
                            <td>Activity</td>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant-or-self::ChildTerm"/>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ChildTerm">
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*[@Entity='Term']">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
                </td>               
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applying the template will produce this HTML table

```
<table>
<tbody><tr>
<td>Process</td>
<td>Function</td>
<td>Activity</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ENVIRONMENTAL MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Auditing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ENVIRONMENTAL MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Auditing</td>
<td>Environmental audit</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ENVIRONMENTAL MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Auditing</td>
<td>Type of audit []</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ENVIRONMENTAL MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Incidents</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ENVIRONMENTAL MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Incidents</td>
<td>Bruce Beresford</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ENVIRONMENTAL MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Incidents</td>
<td>Case name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ENVIRONMENTAL MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Incidents</td>
<td>Jack Lemmon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ENVIRONMENTAL MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Incidents</td>
<td>Mary  Pcikford</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ENVIRONMENTAL MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Monitoring</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ENVIRONMENTAL MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Policies and procedures</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>HUMAN RESOURCE MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Agreements</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>HUMAN RESOURCE MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Leave</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>HUMAN RESOURCE MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Leave</td>
<td>Annual leave</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>HUMAN RESOURCE MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Leave</td>
<td>Annual leave</td>
<td>Name of position</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>HUMAN RESOURCE MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Leave</td>
<td>Annual leave</td>
<td>Type of audit []</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>HUMAN RESOURCE MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Leave</td>
<td>Annual leave</td>
<td>Type of product</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>HUMAN RESOURCE MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Leave</td>
<td>Maternity leave</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>HUMAN RESOURCE MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Performance management</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>HUMAN RESOURCE MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Recruiting</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>HUMAN RESOURCE MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Recruiting</td>
<td>Name of position</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>HUMAN RESOURCE MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Remuneration</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>HUMAN RESOURCE MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Insurance</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

My question is: How do I remove the `<tr>` that only has 2 `<td>` IF and only IF the below `<tr>` has the same 2 `<td>` with an extra 3rd `<td>`

For example, this will be removed

```
<tr>
<td>ENVIRONMENTAL MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Auditing</td>
</tr>
```

because the `<tr>` below has

```
<tr>
<td>ENVIRONMENTAL MANAGEMENT</td>
<td>Auditing</td>
<td>Type of audit []</td>
</tr>
```

Hope my question is clear, or else please tell me, I'll edit. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following template to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="TopTerm/ChildTerm[ChildTerm]"/>
```

Comment: Nice!! It works. Can you please explain why? I'm still new to XSLT stuff

Comment: @Jack It matches the ChildTerms that are children of TopTerm (i.e. second in the hierarchy) **and** have children of their own. These are precisely the ChildTerms whose rows you wish to eliminate - and they *are* eliminated because the template tells the stylesheet to do nothing with the matched nodes. Note also that the match pattern is more specific than just `"ChildTerm"` - so this one takes priority over the more general template.